# Delphi Tokyo - Function: String to Hex and Hex to String

Tags: string, function, delphi, hex

The function below works perfectly to convert string to hexadecimal:

```
function String2Hex(const Buffer: AnsiString): string;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Buffer) * 2);
  BinToHex(@Buffer[1], PWideChar(@Result[1]), Length(Buffer));
end;

ShowMessage(String2Hex('stackoverflow'));
```

This result: "737461636B6F766572666C6F77"

The problem is in the function of converting hexadecimal to string:

```
function Hex2String(const Buffer: AnsiString): string;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Buffer) div 2);
  HexToBin(PWideChar(@Buffer[1]), @Result[1], Length(Buffer));
end;

ShowMessage(Hex2String('737461636B6F766572666C6F77'));
```

The result should be "stackoverflow" but nothing happens.

Could someone help me?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.HexToBin) still say *The hexadecimal number must use lowercase characters; HexToBin does not recognize uppercase characters. For example: "ACDC66" is an invalid string, you must use "acdc66" instead.* See the section on the Text parameter, first bulleted item. I see from your comment below that you've reported it as a doc error. Thanks for pointing it out here. I'll delete my comments in a few minutes, after you've had a chance to see this reply.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

1. You are type-casting your input `AnsiString` incorrectly to `PWideChar`, so you are calling the wrong overload of `HexToBin()`. `PWideChar` should be `PAnsiChar` instead.
2. The `BufSize` parameter of `HexToBin()` specifies the number of bytes the output buffer expects to receive, but you are passing it the number of characters in the hex string instead.

Also, since `String2Hex()` takes an `AnsiString` and returns a `UnicodeString`, `Hex2String()` should take `UnicodeString` and return an `AnsiString` to match.

Try this instead:

```
function String2Hex(const Buffer: AnsiString): string;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Buffer) * 2);
  BinToHex(PAnsiChar(Buffer), PChar(Result), Length(Buffer));
end;

function Hex2String(const Buffer: string): AnsiString;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Buffer) div 2);
  HexToBin(PChar(Buffer), PAnsiChar(Result), Length(Result));
end;
```

```
var
  hex: string;
  str: AnsiString;
begin
  hex := String2Hex('stackoverflow');
  ShowMessage(hex); // shows '737461636B6F766572666C6F77'
  str := Hex2String(hex);
  ShowMessage(str); // shows 'stackoverflow'
end;
```

Comment: Point '3' is an error in documentation. HexToBin accounts for uppercase letters since at least D7 (older version I can check is D3, which doesn't have the function at all).

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: you are right, I misread the code when I checked it before posting. FYI, the support of uppercase goes all the way back to at least Delphi 5, if not 4 (but it didn't ignore non-hex characters `#58..#64,#91..#96` until Delphi 2009).

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: I reported the documentation error: [RSP-19625](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19625)

Comment: firemonkey in android dont have `PAnsiChar` and `AnsiString`

Comment: @peimanF. So just use `String` and `PChar` instead. You don't need `AnsiString` support to use hex strings. `Bin2Hex()` and `Hex2Bin()` are overloaded for Unicode strings. Otherwise, install Andreas Hausladen's [ByteStrings patch](https://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2013/10/the-return-of-the-byte-strings/).